# Group a collection of strings by their hash value

Tags: c#, collections, hash

I have a list of users ranging from 1 to several thousands.
All of the users have a list of attributes on which I must perform an analysis.
Most users have between 5 and 20 different attributes, but some could have as many as 100.

I have created a `Dictionary<string, Collection<string>>` where Key is the UserId and Value is the user's attributes.

Now instead of performing an analysis on each individual user I was thinking that I could group the users by their attributes. Ie if several users have the same attributes, the result will be the same.

Which leads me to my question; can I somehow generate a hash value from a string Collection?

Comment: Yes for example XORing them. But you will have collisions. `string1.GetHashCode() == string2.GetHashCode()` doesn't imply `string1 == string2`

Comment: Is it possible for you to refactor your code in order to create a UserAttributes class instead of storing attributes in a Collection<string> ?

Comment: Not to mention that implementation of GetHashCode() is platform dependant!

Comment: Are the "attributes" that each user can have a defined set, or just random?

Comment: This is too abstract, at least for me. Could you show a simple class with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a hash from anything -- including individual strings or a collection of strings. And you can use a simple algorithm or a complex one. A simple example for a string collection would be to simply calculate the sum of the lengths of all strings, then MOD by a prime number such as 32003.

That would be a bad hash for your purposes, but it illustrates that calculating a hash is just a matter of determining what is important to you, or what will distinguish elements enough.

The problem with hashing for this purpose is that a hash is always a one-way calculation that is in a sense a simplification of the object being hashed. This means that information gets lost and there may be collisions. That is, if hash(x) == hash(y) that does not mean that x == y, unless hash(x) == x for every x.

So grouping based on hash does not imply that you are grouping based on content/values.

That being said, you could calculate a hash where **less bits are lost** -- such as a SHA hash (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm). SHA is based on strings so what you can do is create a JSON/XML serialization of your collection, then calculate a SHA hash on that, and do your grouping based on that SHA hash. SHA is pretty secure and the chance of collisions is pretty slim to say the least.

Therefore, my advice would be: serialize the `Collection` (or rather `List`, because with a `List`, the order of items is guaranteed whereas with a `Collection` it is not) to JSON or XML, calculate a SHA of that, and use that as your grouping value.

Addendum:
To serialize to JSON, you can use the built-in extension in `System.Web.Extensions`:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myList);
```

Then to calculate a SHA1 hash, you can use the provider in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(json);
string hashAsString = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
```